# How to flag all contributors with a specific tag?

Tags: civicontribute, civicontact

I am wondering if it is possible to flag all the contacts who ever made a contribution in the past with a specific tag.

When I search for the contributors and select all of them, no action is available to set a tag on them.

If this is not available through the GUI, a MySQL statement could be a solution.

Comment: If your goal is to Tag contacts, then you need to search via Adv Search, not via Find Contributions. From your description I can't be sure what you are trying.

Comment: As Pete says - but to make clear -, the answer is Adv Search, then add the Contributions criteria then Search and you'll get a list of contacts.  In Actions, select 'Tag - add to contacts' and select a tag.

Comment: I don't see the tab Contributions in Advanced Search. Is this a bug in my system? I run the last version of CiviCRM 5.37.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can tag contacts from the search. Find Contribution list all the contributions and its not possible in current system to tag contribution, so action option would be available from Find contribution to tag the results.

As said by Andy and Pete, you will need to Advance search to the the contacts based on the criteria and choose the 'Tag - Add to contact' action.

[image]

Comment: When go to the "Advanced Search" Screen, I don't see the tab Contributions: see [screenshot](https://mega.nz/file/kt83FIpQ#9KnhZBDHECSMrcypoZg2svcBuvJNkJb2pBKoQ9rpj9I). How is it possible to fix this?

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/39547/155

Answer (score 1):

I'd answer this in a slightly different way, the question was tagging contributions and not contacts, my assumption is that there is a need to hold metadata against a contribution. We have a similar requirement in the UK for knowing if a specific contribution can have gift aid tax claims made against it or if the contribution already has been claimed etc.

So my answer, assuming this is the case, would be that you first need to add a custom field to the contributions to had the tag/indicator you wish to record about the contribution.

You could then follow two paths to mark them, one is using bulk profile update in a similar fashion to the previous answers. The second method would be to bulk export, tag and reimport. The choice depends on the number of contributions etc. There are relatively minor developments you could also do to make the process much easier - for instance using Rules to automatically mark/update the contributions with the relevant metadata.

Hope that makes sense!