# When I go to the "Advanced Search" Screen, I don't see the tab Contributions

Tags: civicontribute, civicontact

When I go to the "Advanced Search" Screen, I don't see the tab Contributions for searching on the fields related to donations.

[image]

Is this a bug or the consequence of having activated only the CiviContribute, CiviMail and CiviReport components? Should I activate another component? Which one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable it in Display Preferences. Navigate to
CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize Data and Screens >> Display Preferences.
Check the contribution option under 'Contact Search' field.